# Cannot plot in Pycharm using matplotlib.pyplot.. The figure showed up and disappeared instantly

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, figure

In Pycharm

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.interactive(True)
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
```

The figure showed up and disappeared instantly.

How to set the figure to keep showing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are in interactive mode the figure will not stay open. You may simply not use interactive mode,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()
```

or you may turn it off before showing the figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.interactive(True)
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `plt.show()`, i.e.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()
```